# How to prevent a "Bluetooth keyboard setup. There isn't a keyboard connected" message at startup

Tags: keyboard, macos, bluetooth, mac-mini

I am using a Mac mini. It does not have a keyboard or mouse attached to it. This is by design because I only want to connect remotely to it.

I notice that everytime I reboot my machine. The machine boot sequence gets stuck on a message "Bluetooth Keyboard Setup." There isn't a keyboard connected and it has a circling wheel which says "No keyboards have been found. Make sure your keyboard is discoverable".

I don't want this message. I want my Mac mini to boot fully to a state where someone can remotely connect to it without being blocked by this keyboard message.

**How can I do this?**

I have already disabled bluetooth on the Mac mini, but it still gets blocked at this screen when it boots.

Comment: Actually, I notice this during sleep as well.  I will come back and it fails to detect my keyboard and trackpad.  After banging on some function keys (or perhaps after a time period has passed) things return to normal on their own.

Comment: @ Allan - I just wanted to thank you for responding to the question about the Bluetooth keyboard issue. I had the same question relating to my headless Mac Mini and did a Google search and this Q&A came up. I appreciate having a technical question and being able to quickly find the answer because people like you take the time to answer these questions. I know you did this back in 2017, but your help is still valid now in 2023 - 6 years later. All the best - hope you’re doing well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have to turn off Bluetooth Assistant.**

In *Preferences, Bluetooth*, click the *Advanced* button, then uncheck "Open Bluetooth Assistant at Startup if no keyboard is detected."

[image]
[image]

Once you turn it off, you should have no problems booting in a headless configuration.

Comment: @ Allan - I just wanted to thank you for responding to the question about the Bluetooth keyboard issue. I had the same question relating to my headless Mac Mini and did a Google search and this Q&A came up. I appreciate having a technical question and being able to quickly find the answer because people like you take the time to answer these questions. I know you did this back in 2017, but your help is still valid now in 2023 - 6 years later. All the best - hope you’re doing well!